# How to write a make_pair like function for bitset, make_bitset?

Tags: c++, templates

Because c++ cannot deduce class template arguments from constructor, as a workaround, we write a make function like std::make_pair.

My question is: Dose this work for std::bitset?  In other words, can I write a function  make_bitset(7) which returns bitset<7>?

My attempt is:

```
template<size_t N>
bitset<N> make_bitset(size_t N){
    return bitset<N>();
}
```

It seems not work.

Comment: Yes, but the `7` has to be a constant, so you could just as well write `bitset<7>()`.

Comment: `N` should be know at compile time, providing it at run-time wound't help.

Comment: That won't get shorter than `bitset<N>()`.

Comment: Not even `constexpr` and or UDLs can save you here. The only thing that would come close here is (eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!) `#define make_bitset(N) (std::bitset<N>())`

Comment: Mmm. Actually: it ***does*** get shorter: `template <size_t N> using bs = std::bitset<N>;` **[http://ideone.com/Q89e6A](http://ideone.com/Q89e6A)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mfontanini said, "you won't get shorter `bitset<N>()`". However, you could initialise it with a `char const[]`.

```
template<size_t N>
std::bitset<N-1> make_bitset(char const (&in_string)[N])
{
    return std::bitset<N-1>(in_string);
}
```

Therefore, instead of writing `bitset<3> my_bitset("100");`, you could write `auto my_bitset = make_bitset("100");`.

Notice how `N` is implied by the type passed in, not actually passed in itself.

Comment: It won't work at least because, lets say, "100" is `const char [4]`!

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. Encode N in an array and let the compiler deduces N from the array. @mfontanini is right. it doesn't get any shorter.

Comment: @IgorR. Ah the details :P

Comment: Ok, it's better now, but still... it seems `N` won't be deduced :).

Comment: @IgorR. I fixed that. However, -1 because this is highly unintuitive, and in the end doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Mmm. Actually: it ***does*** get shorter: `template <size_t N> using bs = std::bitset<N>;` **[http://ideone.com/Q89e6A](http://ideone.com/Q89e6A)**

Comment: @sehe I don't think this is highly unintuitive at all. All of the `make_*` functions deduce their template arguements from the types that are passed in, which is what the OP appeared to be confused about. Ok, I made a syntactic error and thanks for fixing that.

Comment: @sehe Why is this *"unintuitive and doesn't solve anything"*? It at least solves the case when you got a bit pattern as string literal and are too lazy to count up the bits. Of course each case of automatic type deduction could be solved by just deducing the correct type yourself, but well... Still you're right in that it might not solve the problem of the OP trying to create a bitset from a runtime value (but I'm not sure this was really his goal), but at least it presents an interresting approach and probably the best automatic deduction you can get for a `std::bitset`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Having to pass `make_bitset("1234567")` to get... `std::bitset<7>` is ***not*** intuitive. No debate. Not to mention `make_bitset("0123")`, `make_bitset("0x07")` :}

Comment: PS. I seem to have missed the 'point' about using the string value as initializer (probably because it is not what the OP was talking about)

Comment: @sehe *"Because c++ cannot deduce class template arguments from constructor, as a workaround, we write a make function like std::make_pair."* The OP was experimenting with functions like `make_pair`. I'm not sure he really cares how.